# What kind of images should i use for my android app

Tags: android, image

i am developing an android app and i want an image as a wallpaper and some other images. Should i create these images myself or there are some android libraries where i can download images for my app which i want to publish it in Google play.

Comment: You can download the images. If you want to use images that scale well,use 9patch images. 9patch is also the preferred image format

Comment: Thank you for your answer Radix. I just want to ask if you know any site(s) which provides images for commercial use without having copyright issues

Comment: Try this link : http://www.flaticon.com/

Comment: To avpid copyright issues , just give the designer credit in ur app :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what you're after. If you want a static background or other images, then use a `.png` with different densities (i.e. hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi) more about densities: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

If you want to use images for buttons, or other widgets you should look into 9patches, using 9patches means you can completely resize the image in your app without any scaling problems, more about 9patches: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

But, if you have an image which is likely to change, i.e. a users profile picture you should probably look at loading it from a URL into an `ImageView` something like Picasso by square: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Hope this helps.